# Create a class which contains the items to draw (seg fault)

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, sfml

I'm struggling with a code that I think... should be very easy. But I don't know why, I don't understand how to make it correctly.

I'm trying to store all instances of `sf::Drawable` in a `std::vector`.
The problem is, the `sf::Drawable` class is abstract, so I have to use pointers, I know it, it's correct.

I'm trying to render the items part by part, so I'm using `std::vector<std::vector<sf::Drawable*>>`, and if you have any idea on how to make something better than it, I'll gladly accept it, because I hate vectors of vectors, it looks dangerously big, and I'm sure it uses a lot of memory (I try to keep it to 3 parts max).

The problem is, when I add a pointer in the Page class (where I store all the pointers to the drawable things), it causes a segfault if the sprite goes out of scope, which is normal. The thing is, I don't know how to prevent the program from deleting the sprite, because I don't want my main class (named Game) to keep the sprites, texts, ...

Here is the code, it should be clearer :

Page.cpp :

```
#include "Page.h"

void Page::AddSprite(int coat, sf::Drawable* sprite) {

    if (coat < m_sprites.size())
        m_sprites[coat].push_back(sprite);

    else
        m_sprites.push_back(std::vector<sf::Drawable*>(1, sprite));
}

std::vector<std::vector<sf::Drawable*>>* Page::GetSprites() {
    return &m_sprites;
}
```

Page.h :

```
#ifndef PAGE_H
#define PAGE_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Page
{
    public:
        Page();

        void AddSprite(int coat, sf::Drawable* sprite);

        std::vector<std::vector<sf::Drawable*>>* GetSprites();

    protected:
        std::vector<std::vector<sf::Drawable*>> m_sprites;
    private:
};

#endif // PAGE_H
```

Game.cpp :

```
Game::Game() : m_numberItems(20) {}

void Game::Run() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), "Lost Items | Items remaining : " + std::to_string(m_numberItems));

    LoadSprites();

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::White);

        std::vector<std::vector<sf::Drawable*>>* pageSprites = m_page.GetSprites();
        for (int i = 0; i < pageSprites->size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < pageSprites->at(i).size(); j++) {
                window.draw((*(pageSprites->at(i)[j])));
            }
        }

        window.display();
    }
}

void Game::LoadSprites() {
    int CASE_LEN = CASE_LENGTH; // It was after a copy paste from another class, and I didn't want to change all the CASE_LEN to CASE_LENGTH
    for (short i = 0; i < m_numberItems; i++) {
        int x = rand() % ((SCREEN_WIDTH - CASE_LEN) / CASE_LEN);
        int y = rand() % ((SCREEN_HEIGHT - CASE_LEN) / CASE_LEN);
        sf::Sprite sprite(m_graphics.GetTilesTexture());
        sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(ITEM_X, ITEM_Y, CASE_LEN, CASE_LEN));
        sprite.setPosition(x * CASE_LEN, y * CASE_LEN);
        m_page.AddSprite(0, &sprite);
    }
}
```

Game.h :

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Page.h"

class Game
{
    public:
        Game();
        void Run();
        void LoadSprites();

        /** @brief The window width.*/
        static const unsigned short SCREEN_WIDTH = 1280;

        /** @brief The window height */
        static const unsigned short SCREEN_HEIGHT = 736;

        /** @brief The case length. */
        static const unsigned short CASE_LENGTH = 32;

    protected:

        unsigned char m_numberItems;
        Page m_page;

#endif // GAME_H
```

I hope I've been clear enough, and thank you for your answers !

P.S. : I thought I could use unique pointers (`std::unique_ptr<sf::Drawable>`) but I don't know how to use them, because I can't use `std::make_unique<sf::Drawable>` because of the abstraction of `sf::Drawable`).

Comment: Use smartpointers, in your case std::shared_ptr

Comment: Why std::shared_ptr and not std::unique_ptr ? I'm not sure of the difference between them... ^^' And also, how to initialize it ? Because I've never done it with an abstract class :c

Comment: `page.GetSprites()` could return `std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::Drawable>>>`. And then you can ask another question - "how to use unique_ptr". Or use `shared_ptr` - it depends on the lifecycle of the sprites

Comment: You need somethink like `std::unique_ptr<Abstract> p = std::make_unique<Concrete>(...);`.

Comment: @RustyX thanks, I'll try that ^^ but why do you say unique_ptr while LeDYoM says it's better to use shared_ptr ? (if it's not too offtopic). And thanks Jarod, I'll try that !

Comment: I would go in for shared in this case. In general, when working in a game, the design of the scene graph tend to require shared_ptrs. I am not specifying a real rule here, because of course, it depends on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: @LeDYoM thanks for your answer ^^ I think I need to learn smart pointers more, so I can understand them totally ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
{
    sf::Sprite sprite(m_graphics.GetTilesTexture());

    // ...
    m_page.AddSprite(0, &sprite);
}
```

You store local variable and so have dangling reference at end of the scope.

You may do something like (using smart pointer)

```
{
    auto sprite = std::make_unique<sf::Sprite>(m_graphics.GetTilesTexture());

    // ...
    m_page.AddSprite(0, std::move(sprite));
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! That's a bit different than what you said in your comment (which worked correctly), but I'll give a shot to that solution too, it seems really good ^^ Thank you again, a lot !